# how to remove lines based on integer n?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to alternate a file but keeping some lines intact based on a user input. (Details below code)

```
public class RemoveLines {
public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    // prompt for input file name
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Type first file name to use: ");
    String filename1 = console.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Type second file name to use: ");
    String filename2 = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter an integer: ");
    int n = console.nextInt();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename1));   //put the first file as input
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File(filename2)); //put the second file as output
    int count =0;
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        count ++;
        while(n<=count){
            output.println(); // this is where i don't know what to place

        }
    }
}   
}
```

the program should prompt the user to enter 2 file names and an integer n. 
it should create a second file that contains the first n lines of the first file, while keeping it intact. If the first file contains less than n lines then the second file will contain all the lines of the first file.
i've started writing the while loop, but i am not sure what command i should include in order to have the desired output.
thank you.

Comment: that's if, not while, and your else should contain a break.

Comment: Is given `filename1` is exist? Otherwise it will throw `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: @Masud yes filename1 exists

Comment: It's also `count<=n`, rather than `n<=count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with the following code:

```
 int count = 0;
    while (count < n) {
        if (input.hasNextLine()) {
            output.println(input.nextLine()); // this is where i don't know what to place
            count++;
        }else
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Close scanner 
     */

    input.close();
    console.close();
    output.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(input.hasNextLine()){
   count ++;
   while(n<=count){
      output.println(input.nextLine()); 
   } else {
      break;
   }
}
```

You should also check the the input file exists.
And also you should close your input and output. I will not matter in this trivial case but it's something you should do in more complex applications.

Answer (score 0):

You should open PrintStream with the append option set to true (which is false by default) -

```
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File(filename2, **true**));
```

Then you can do something like below -

```
String inputLine = scanner.readLine(); 
output.append(inputLine);
```